# What Do I Need to Compose/Create/Mix Music Fully Digitally?

Tags: audio, software, windows, daw

I want to write some music, maybe mix other songs as well. I want to be able to write up some melodies/harmonies, or lay down some beats and mix them to my heart's content, with different instruments (or vocals?) and so forth, but I don't want to deal with physically recording it myself. Most importantly, I have some money to spend on software, but **I do not have space to put lots of hardware!** I want to have the option of taking my laptop to the airport and making music on my layover if I want to.  So I'll obviously need some high-quality sample libraries along with composition software and nice headphones.

My question is, what else is actually **necessary**? I presumably need a DAW of some kind, but I have no reference point for their quality. Do I need (or should I get anyway) a separate program for writing out compositions in real notation? Is there any way to integrate these two things, or software that does both?

I suppose this is as much a workflow question as anything else. Whatever software I end up with, I'd like my process to feel a little more organized than just haphazardly dropping samples onto tracks. I run **Windows** (XP and 7), for what that's worth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the minimum down already - a laptop, a DAW, and some headphones. You don't *need* anything else. Other things *may* be useful to you, but aren't necessary.

If you are classically trained, you *may* want notation software. But even then, a good notebook and pen will probably do just fine.

> Whatever software I end up with, I'd like my process to feel a little more organized than just haphazardly dropping samples onto tracks.

You should probably do some reading on project management, creativity, and process-driven art. Modern DAWs are extremely flexible, so pick one that fits within your budget and appeals to you. Then develop a workflow that allows you to effective express your creativity.

There is no need to spend a lot of money initially. There are very inexpensive DAWs out there (Reaper, Renoise) as well as low cost "starter" versions of the more expensive DAWs. Similarly, there are a lot of [free sample libraries](http://creativecommons.org/weblog/entry/8163) that may or may not be useful for you.